# Google adword api ruby - How to get all keywords of campaign?

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

I used `google adword api` with `ruby client` to create and update keywords. I need to create and update quite much `ad groups` (5.000 ad groups) and have no problem with create new ad groups and keywords.

But I have problem when I want to get all keywords. I have to loop all of ad_group_id to get all keyword like [example of ruby client](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby/blob/master/adwords_api/examples/v201502/basic_operations/get_keywords.rb)

```
def current_ga_data
  ga_data = {}
  ad_group_ids =  get_all_ad_group_ids
  return {} if ad_group_ids.blank?
  ad_group_ids.each do |ad_group_id|
    ga_data[ad_group_id] = get_keywords(ad_group_id)
  end
end
```

There are many queries and take a long time to get all keywords.

So please point me how to get all keywords of one campaign (don't need to loop ad_group_id) or another way to get all keywords with much of ad groups?

[Google adword api ruby client](https://github.com/googleads/google-api-ads-ruby)

Comment: Why don't you use the KEYWORD PERFORMANCE REPORT?

Answer (score 0):

It takes long because you are making a request for each `ad_group_id`. What you should do is make an array with all `ad_group_ids` and then make a request with an where clause "keyword in ad_group_id".